# Python Threads - Changing number of parallel threads on the fly

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

I am trying out concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor to run a few jobs in parallel. It lets me set the max_workers once, at the initialization time. But for some reason, my requirement is to change the number of active threads on the fly. I couldn't find any way to do that. Tried resetting the "_max_workers" on the fly, but that had no impact.

Here's the code.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
import urllib.request
from random import randint
from time import sleep

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']

# Retrieve a single page and report the url and contents
def load_url(url, timeout):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
        return conn.read()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(1)
    fs = []
    for url in URLS:
        fs.append(pool.submit(load_url, url, 60))

    r = randint(1,5)
    print ("Changing max_workers to: {}".format(r))
    pool._max_workers = r
    print ("Current queue size: {}. Number of threads in parallel: {}".format(pool._work_queue.qsize(), len(pool._threads)))

    for f in as_completed(fs):
        r = randint(1,5)
        print ("Changing max_workers to: {}".format(r))
        pool._max_workers = r
        print ("Current queue size: {}. Number of threads in parallel: {}".format(pool._work_queue.qsize(), len(pool._threads)))

        try:
            data = f.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
        else:
            print('Page is %d bytes' % (len(data)))

    print ("done")
```

Here's what it prints:

```
Changing max_workers to: 3  
Current queue size: 4. Number of threads in parallel: 1  
Changing max_workers to: 1  
Current queue size: 3. Number of threads in parallel: 1  
Page is 233315 bytes  
Changing max_workers to: 4  
Current queue size: 2. Number of threads in parallel: 1  
Page is 1127911 bytes  
Changing max_workers to: 2  
Current queue size: 1. Number of threads in parallel: 1  
Page is 2741410 bytes  
Changing max_workers to: 4  
Current queue size: 0. Number of threads in parallel: 1  
Page is 296361 bytes  
done
```

Is there a way I can change the max_worker which will change the active threads in pool._threads?

Answer (score 0):

Well, couldn't figure out how to get this done using concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor, but still managed to change the number of active threads at runtime, with some custom logic around threading.

Here's the final working code - https://github.com/gireeshp/API-Hitting-Simulator